# Evaluating $\int_{\pi/4}^ { \pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos²(x)}} \text{d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate this integral

$$\int_{\pi/4}^ { \pi/2}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}} \text{d}x  $$

but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: For me this looks like you will nee elliptic integrals (it is equivalent to the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx$ which is known to be an elliptic one)

Comment: thank's a loot my friend i will see this kind of integrals :)

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}} ~=~ \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}} ~=~ \frac{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite slightly (using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$):

$$
I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)}}dx$$

Looking up wikipedia this is the standardform of $\text{F}(x|a)$, ( [elliptic integrals of the first typ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)) with $a=\sqrt\frac{1}{2}$ .

$$
I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{F}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{F}(\frac{\pi}{4}|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})
$$

Answer (score 1):

By setting $x=\arctan u$ we are left with:

$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1+u^2}}}=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(1+u^2)(2+u^2)}}$$
that can be written in terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), namely as a difference between a complete elliptic integral of the first kind and an incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind. Unluckily, I do not believe that can be simplified further. As a positive counterpart, the [AGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) gives a very fast-converging algorithm for the numerical evaluation of such integrals. Ultimately, that boils down to noticing that:

$$ (1+u^2)(2+u^2) = ((\sqrt{2}-1)u)^2 + (u^2+\sqrt{2})^2$$
by Lagrange's identity.